# Unexpected token '}'

Tags: javascript

I'm trying to get a basic hangman game to work and keep getting back `Line 25 unexpected token '}'`.

I've looked and looked and I have taken out the brackets. I've just had the one there but I can't get anything to work. The `}` just above the `var remainingletters` is the one it keeps saying is missing.

Here are a couple of the lines:

```
var answerArray = [];

for (var i = 0; i < word.length; i++) {
    answerArray[i] = "_",
}

var remainingLetters = word.length;
```

Comment: should the ',' maybe be an ';'? after answerArray[i] = "_"

Comment: Your for loop is an object?

Comment: Comma (`'`) to semi colon (`;`)

Comment: @ManhLe You say comma but show an apostrophe... good job. :P

Comment: @Clonkex: what a typo :)) Thanks for pointing.
P/s: Change from `,` to `;` at the end of statement inside loop.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have a small typo - you used a comma at the end of a line where you need a semicolon -

```
var answerArray = [];
for (var i = 0; i < word.length; i++) {
    answerArray[i] = "_";
}

var remainingLetters = word.length;
```

Comment: That was it, Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

You have to change this code

```
answerArray[i] = "_ ,
```

to this ;

```
answerArray[i] = "_" ;
```

---

We always have to end lines with semicolon, your code have uncompleted line which is end with comma and you get error because of you try to close if condition before end the line.

Comment: Could you highlight the difference? It is very hard to see if you do not know for what to look for. Possibly you could also explain the change, why it was needed and where the problem was. That helps OP more than just "*do this and that*".

Comment: @Zabuza i'm new in here. I try to explain why you have to do it. My english not good that enough

Comment: That is no problem, others can always edit your answer to fix grammar issues or something like that. It is better now, awesome!